# How to set custom attribute value in HTML DOM using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

**Expecting output:** `<span customAttr="customAttrValue" customAttr2="customAttrValue2"></span>`

**This is what I'm getting:** `<span></span>` using the below code.

```
 /* creates a dom element
 * @param {string} type element type
 * @param {object} attr element attributes
 * @returns {node} html element
 */
function addElement(type, attr) {
    var el = document.createElement(type),
        val;
    for (val in attr) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(attr, val)) {
            el[val] = attr[val];
        }
    }
    return el;
}

 spanWithCustomAttr = addElement('span', {
     setAttribute: ('customAttr', 'customAttrValue'),
     setAttribute: ('customAttr2', 'customAttrValue2')
 });

 appendChild(spanWithCustomAttr);
```

**But when I tried the below code:**

```
spanWithCustomAttr = addElement('span', {
     dir: ('customAttr', 'customAttrValue')
 });

 appendChild(spanWithCustomAttr);
```

**Output:** `<span dir="customAttrValue"></span>`

I don't need `dir` I need my `customAttr` instead. If anyone could help what I'm missing would be awesome.

Comment: [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: @4castle I'm using Vanilla JS, for more clarification I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works, I do not know if that's what you ask.

```js
var data =  { tooltip: "hello" };

function addElement(type, attr) {
    var el = document.createElement(type),
        val;
    for (val in attr) {
     if(attr.hasOwnProperty(val))
         el.setAttribute(val, attr[val]);
    }
    return el;
}

 var element = addElement('span', {
     tooltip: data.tooltip,
     flow: 'right'
 });

element.innerText = "SPAN";  
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

```css
span{background:red;width:50px;display:block;height:20px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```